# I have a question about learning evolution

Tags: science

All my life I have attended Bais Yaakov. I am frum but for mental health issues I decided to take a break from Bais Yaakov, and am taking online courses. In my biology course evolution is taught as a unit. If I skip this unit it means I haven't completed the course and I won't have enough credits to graduate.

The way my program works is: For each subject, I have all my lessons, a text book to read, and I need to take quizzes and write essays. I have been enrolled since September.  The unit was far off then, but now it's getting closer. It's now one unit away and I'll probably finish the current bio unit by this week. I could always skip over to the unit after evolution but the bottom line is- I need to do the evolution unit eventually, and I'm stuck between knowing I shouldn't learn it, and just doing it, keeping in mind I don't believe any of it. After all, it is a pretty ridiculous idea that people come from monkeys. I fully believe in Hashem. I'm in no way going otd. I haven't told my parents about this issue yet and I'm too embarrased to call a rav on my own.

In BY this would have never been an issue, and now I feel guilty that I needed to take a mental health break from school.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, malky! I think you should really ask your rabbi about this; MY is great for a lot of things, but [practical halacha is not one of them](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734). I hope to see you around, and that you get a good answer to your question in time! :)

Comment: [These related questions](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bscience%5D+evolution+is%3Aq) might interest you.

Comment: Note that there are many rabbis you could call, and don't have to identify yourself to.